# unable to send mail through Yahoo - skpsmtpmessage

Tags: ios, smtp, yahoo

I downloaded skpsmtpmessage code from Github and ran it on my iphone, it is unable to send any e-mails through my yahoo account. I set
     testMsg.relayHost=@"smtp.mail.yahoo.com" 
but it always fail with "Unsupported login mechanism." or something like that even though I have the right login and password on there. see console log below.

Has anybody tried sending mail thru yahoo with this program?

```
    SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    testMsg.fromEmail = @"mylogin@yahoo.com";
    testMsg.toEmail =   @"mylogin@yahoo.com";
    testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
    testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
    testMsg.login = @"mylogin";
    testMsg.pass = @"mypassword";
    testMsg.subject = @"test message";
    testMsg.wantsSecure = NO; // I tried both YES and NO, neither works
```

Log as follows

```
    2014-04-25 17:10:08.748 SMTPSender[14408:60b] C: Attempting to connect to server at: smtp.mail.yahoo.com:25
    2014-04-25 17:10:08.774 SMTPSender[14408:60b] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.010 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.011 SMTPSender[14408:60b] S: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.011 SMTPSender[14408:60b] C: EHLO localhost
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.012 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** starting short watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.070 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.071 SMTPSender[14408:60b] S: 250-smtp.mail.yahoo.com
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.071 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.071 SMTPSender[14408:60b] S: 250-PIPELINING
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.072 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.072 SMTPSender[14408:60b] S: 250-SIZE 41697280
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.072 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.072 SMTPSender[14408:60b] S: 250-8 BITMIME
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.073 SMTPSender[14408:60b] *** stopping watchdog ***
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.073 SMTPSender[14408:60b] S: 250 STARTTLS
    2014-04-25 17:10:09.074 SMTPSender[14408:60b] delegate - error(-2): Unsupported login mechanism.
```

Any ideas?